# Handle the List-Item of React-native

Tags: react-native

I'm using List-view in react-native.Now, I have to show simple Flat-list after the Four items of my list-view ? How to accomplish this type of thing?

Like This :

```
   <View>
    <ListView>
        ...
<FlatList>
        ...
    </FlatList>
    </ListView>

</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<View>
    <ListView>
        ...
    </ListView>
    <FlatList>
        ...
    </FlatList>
</View>
```

Comment: <View>
    <ListView>
        ...
<FlatList>
        ...
    </FlatList>
    </ListView>
    
</View> like this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve exactly but it seems to me that you could use the ListHeaderComponent prop of the FlatList for this.

Something like this

```
<FlatList 
  ListHeaderComponent={()=> { 
    return <View>
        <ListItem1 />
        <ListItem2 />
        <ListItem3 />
      </View>}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can't add a comment to ask that do you want to render every item of `ListView` that comes after 3 items, as a `FlatList` or want to add an extra `FlatList` after every 3rd item. So I'll try to cover both scenarios here.

If latter is the case you can add some dummy item in `dataSource` at every fourth coming index. and then in `renderRow` apply check as in follow code snippet.

If former is the case then you can put a check in `renderRow method` of 
`ListView` like following:

```
      <ListView
        dataSource={yourDataSource}
        renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID) => {
          if(rowID%4 === 3){
             return <FlatList .../>
          }else {
             return <YourNormalRowItem />
          }
        }}
      />
```

note: here `rowID%4 === 3` is because index start from 0. so it will be like 3, 7, 11 etc.

Comment: @badugabiz did you checked your `rowID`? is it changing for each item of list?